# is can changed [...nextauth].ts file location? in nextauth, keycloak

Tags: next.js, keycloak, openid-connect

redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fhyundai

This is the keycloak redirect_uri address that appears when you press the signIn button.

I can confirm that it is api/auth/callback/hyundai.

Here, hyundai is the ID of keycloakProvider.

I have other ID providers besides Hyundai.

At this time, replace redirect_uri with api/auth/callback/hyundai or api/auth/callback/othername.

Can I use it only with /callback?

Is this possible with the nextauth module?

I wonder if nextauth provides the function by default.